# Dynamic UserControl AddHandler

Tags: vb.net, addhandler

I am trying to understand why my AddHandler isn't working.

I have found a workaround if buttons always on same form but they may not be in the future.

I am also creating these buttons so I can add several variables for later use

Any have a simple answer for me please?

Thanks
Mark

FORM

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For n = 0 To 3
        Dim ctl As New item_button
        AddHandler ctl.Click, AddressOf Me.ClickMe
        ctl.Name = "btn" & n
        ctl.btn.Text = "Button " & n
        ctl.btnID = n
        ctl.Location = New Point(10, n * 50)
        Me.Controls.Add(ctl)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub ClickMe(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'do something
    Dim btn As item_button
    btn = CType(s, item_button)

    TextBox1.Text = "Button " & s.btnID & " was pressed"
End Sub

End Class
```

ITEM_BUTTON

```
Public Class item_button

Public btnID As Integer
Public btnColor As System.Drawing.Color



Public Function ClickIt() As Integer
    Return btnID
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: _"why my AddHandler isn't working_ Do you get an exception?

Answer (score 1):

Your "Button" does not inherit from `Button`:

```
Public Class ItemButton  ' Naming-Conventions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040(v=vs.110).aspx
    Inherits Button

    Public Property BtnID As Integer
    Public Property BtnColor As System.Drawing.Color

    Public Function ClickIt() As Integer
        Return btnID
    End Function
End Class
```

Since i'm not sure what you're actually trying to achieve i show you an example with a custom event that is raised in the custom button and handled in the form:

```
Public Class ItemButton
    Inherits Button

    Public Property BtnID As Integer
    Public Property BtnColor As System.Drawing.Color
    Public Event ButtonClicked(sender As ItemButton, buttonID As Int32)

    Private Sub clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
        RaiseEvent ButtonClicked(Me, BtnID)
    End Sub
End Class
```

in the form:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For n = 0 To 3
        Dim ctl As New ItemButton
        AddHandler ctl.ButtonClicked, AddressOf Me.ItemButtonClicked
        ctl.Name = "btn" & n
        ctl.Name = "Button " & n.ToString()
        ctl.btnID = n
        ctl.Location = New Point(10, n * 50)
        Me.Controls.Add(ctl)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub ItemButtonClicked(ByVal btn As ItemButton, ByVal buttonID As Int32)
    TextBox1.Text = "Button " & buttonID & " was pressed"
End Sub
```

Comment: @MarkCooney: I've edited my answer. However i'm not sure why you get the exception. Try to remove the location code.

Comment: I have added your example code to the project but the Inherits Button cause the following, Error 1 Base class 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' specified for class 'item_button' cannot be different from the base class 'System.Windows.Forms.UserControl' of one of its other partial types. C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\CashRegister\item_button.vb 2 14 CashRegister

Comment: Tim, i'm not getting an exception, just not firing

Answer (score 0):

Sorted

```
Private Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
    RaiseEvent ButtonClicked(Me, btnID)
End Sub
```

Thanks Tim, your code helped